# Pantone Color Bridge - EURO or SWOP

Tags: cmyk, color-profile, pantone

I am going to buy Pantone Color Bridge guide, but I know that it has SWOP and EURO version. I am working for clients around the world. Should I buy two versions? Is SWOP version different than EURO version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note Pantone Color Bridge is no longer produced in different versions such as SWOP and EURO version. There is only one edition of Pantone Color bridge which has most of the solid colors of Pantone Formula Guide in RGB format.

The Pantone Color Bridge is however sold in 3 formats.

Pantone Color Bridge Coated and Uncoated

Pantone Color Bridge Coated

Pantone Color Bridge Uncoated

Answer (score 1):

Most of the difference between those books are based on usability and availability, meaning european paper has a different composition than american (true story) so inks react and settle differently. Printers are also configured different because of this and as you can imagine now, thats why there are also different inks for both "systems". Even software (Photoshop and such) can pre-configure its original settings based on your location to adapt of what is available around "there".

You can always find either one ore two crazy providers with both configs, but in my experience... it is mostly by luck. So yeah, if you do have international clients, you gotta get both books. Colours do change, some by micro details, some by a hughhhe gap, so it would be a gamble.

Comment: So all values (RGB and CMYK) for pantone colors from EURO version will be different in SWOP version, right?

Comment: I was informed that are no longer available different versions (SWOP, EURO, JAPAN) of Pantone Color Bridge guide - exists only one version around the world.

Comment: Be careful, I've heard that many times and found out it wasn't :/ , I bought my both sets last year from an official reseller, meaning there are still out there. And yes, values do change from one book to another!